# Change UIBarButtonItem when UITableView editing state changes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I know this is possible, and I think I'm missing something obvious, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I'm trying to change the `UIBarButtonItem` from one item to another based on whether the `UITableView` is in editing mode. So far, I've done

```
@IBOutlet var btnAddFriend: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var btnFriendRequests: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var tblFriendsList: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var ntbFriendList: UINavigationItem!


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ntbFriendList.rightBarButtonItem = btnAddFriend
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    ntbFriendList.rightBarButtonItem = btnFriendRequests
}
```

but neither function triggers when the editing mode is toggled.

Any help?

Comment: Did you implement tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: @rdelmar no I didn't.

Comment: Well, you need to. I doesn't even need any code in it, you just need to implement it.

Comment: @rdelmar I did that, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: How are you toggling edit mode? In code, or by swiping the cell?

Comment: @rdelmar by using the `self.editButtonItem()` button.

Comment: That doesn't trigger those methods. You have to swipe the cell. Look at the discussion in the docs for the method, 
tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @rdelmar what method(s) would I use to catch toggling the edit mode?

Comment: If your purpose is to change that rightBarButtonItem, why don't you put the code to do that inside the action method for your self.editButtonItem?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not sure I understand. What method are you suggesting I override?

Comment: Don't use the button you get with self.editButtonItem since it has a default method. Create your own rightBarButtonItem, and give it a target and action. Put your code inside that action method.